# Kernel panic after installing a driver with ndiswrapper

Tags: wireless, drivers, usb, kernel

So during my quest to get TL-WN821N, I got stopped by this problem..

I installed all the ndiswrapper programs with `sudo apt-get install`. They were, commons, utils-1.9, source, gtk and something else I think.

So I got it all installed, restarted and so far so good. Now I installed my USB wifi card driver which was for XP 64bit.

Another restart and bam:

[image]

So what is this and how can I recover from this?
Booting Ubuntu in recovery mode will produce the same error.

Comment: Probably a bug or incompatibility. What does the text above this say? Use shift-pageup to scroll.

Comment: Why are you trying to use ndiswrapper? Your card is supported by the ath9k driver.

Comment: Because the ath9k driver seems to work only if I use internet via CLI. When I open a browser, internet does not work anymore. It's a weird bug and noone can tell me what causes it.

Comment: There is nothing special about a gui process that accesses the internet, versus a cli process, they both use exactly the same functions from the same libraries.

Comment: I know, but that is the problem. I can use internet for days with CLI but once I open whatever browser and open like 2 pages, connection is gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably due to a bug in the driver or in ndiswrapper. Have you Googled, to see if other people have had success using ndiswrapper with that same device/driver?

To recover, basically: boot a Live CD, `chroot` into your installation, remove offending driver. Say your root partition is `/dev/sda1`, then after booting the Live CD, do

`sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
sudo mount -t proc none /mnt/proc
sudo mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo chroot /mnt /bin/bash`

(If the second command fails, it's probably because you `mount`ed the wrong partition in the first one.) This will give you a root shell in your installed system, in which you can remove the offending driver from ndiswrapper, or even uninstall ndiswrapper altogether. When you are done, `exit` from the `chroot`ed shell, unmount everything:

`sudo umount /mnt/proc
sudo umount /mnt/dev
sudo umount /mnt`

and reboot normally.

Comment: Will give it a shot soon and report back.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the driver you installed with ndiswarapper. Check if this guide works for you instead. http://myubuntunotes.wordpress.com/2011/03/03/hello-world/